# Javascript : change class attribute value in a tag

Tags: javascript, html, classname

I have an html where I want to change with a javascript function the value of one class attribute.

Here is the html code :

```
<select name="client" class="select form-select" id="id_client" style="display : none "> 
    <option value="1109">Charles</option> 
    <option value="1108">Fred</option> 
    <option value="1107">Lionel</option> 
    <option value="1106">Robert</option> 
    <option value="1105">Mike</option>
</select>
<div class="dropdown dselect-wrapper select">
    <button class="form-select " data-dselect-text="Charles" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Charles
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <input onkeydown="return event.key !== 'Enter'" onkeyup="dselectSearch(event, this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select', false)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autofocus="">
        <div class="dselect-items" style="max-height:360px;overflow:auto">
          <button class="dropdown-item active" data-dselect-value="1109" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Charles</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1108" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Fred</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1107" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Lionel</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1106" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Robert</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1105" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Mike</button>
        </div>
        <div class="dselect-no-results d-none">No results found</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I change value of this class to `class="dropdown-item"`

```
<button class="dropdown-item active" data-dselect-value="1109" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Charles</button>
```

I did that but not sure that it is the right way

```
var old_selected = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item active").className = "dropdown-item";
console.log(old_selected);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one button with `.dropdown-item` and `active` classes, you need to use `querySelectorAll` and loop through and set the `className`

```
document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-item.active").forEach(button => button.className = "dropdown-item");
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-item.active").forEach(button => button.className = "dropdown-item");
```

```css
.dropdown-item.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<select name="client" class="select form-select" id="id_client" style="display : none "> 
    <option value="1109">Charles</option> 
    <option value="1108">Fred</option> 
    <option value="1107">Lionel</option> 
    <option value="1106">Robert</option> 
    <option value="1105">Mike</option>
</select>
<div class="dropdown dselect-wrapper select">
    <button class="form-select " data-dselect-text="Charles" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Charles
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <input onkeydown="return event.key !== 'Enter'" onkeyup="dselectSearch(event, this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select', false)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autofocus="">
        <div class="dselect-items" style="max-height:360px;overflow:auto">
          <button class="dropdown-item active" data-dselect-value="1109" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Charles</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1108" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Fred</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1107" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Lionel</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1106" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Robert</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1105" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Mike</button>
        </div>
        <div class="dselect-no-results d-none">No results found</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
How can I change value of this class to class="dropdown-item"

<button class="dropdown-item active" data-dselect-value="1109" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Charles</button>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try your code ! I have done another question similar to that ! Maybe you want to have a look on it !

Answer (score 1):

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".dropdown-item")
btn.classList.remove('active')
```

this should work for only the first button

the proper way to do it is to get all buttons and remove all of active class

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-item")
btns.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('active'))
```

Comment: This will return the first element that has the className of `dropdown-item`. Not a good solution as it may return the one with the class of `active` or it may not. If you update your selector, to `.dropdown-item.active` it will suffice. But only if the first element found with both classes is the one you want. There are multiple with both class names.